# Integers $d$ for which the negative Pell equation is soluble for both $d$ and $2d$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $\text{NPE}_d$ denote the negative Pell equation:
$$ x^2-dy^2=-1$$
Where $d$ is a given positive nonsquare integer and integer solutions are sought for x and y.

we know that ([in this paper](http://www.numbertheory.org/pdfs/negative_pell.pdf)
[archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20220221052803/http://www.numbertheory.org/pdfs/negative_pell.pdf)):

> **Theorem :** The equation $\text{NPE}_d$ has integer solutions if and only if there exist two integers $a(d)=a$ and $b(d)=b$ such that $d=a^2+b^2$ and there exists a Pythagorean triplet $(A,B,C)$
> such that $|aA-bB|=1$ and in this case $(Aa+Bb,C)$ is a solution.

Obviously if $\text{NPE}_d$ has integer solutions then $d$ cannot be divisible by any prime $p$ such that $p=3\mod 4$.

> My **question**: Is there any characterization for the integers $d$ for which $\text{NPE}_d$ and $\text{NPE}_{2d}$ have both integer solutions.

I used the characterization above, but I can't link the couple $(a(d),b(d))$
to $(a(2d),b(2d))$ because the theorem doesn't give us much information

The sequence  of the elements $d$ for which $\text{NPE}_d$  is soluble is OEIS [A031396](http://oeis.org/A031396).

I posted this question in [math.exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153428/integers-d-for-which-the-negative-pell-equation-is-soluble-for-both-d-and-2) and does not receive any answer

Answer (score 5):

I know the question is old, but is possible to give an exact characterization to $d$, at least if it's a prime number:

It is known that considering a prime $p \equiv 1\mod 4$, there is always a solution to $x^2 - py^2 = -1$ in integers, the proof is from Mordell "Diophantine Equations" pages 55-56 (thanks to @Will Jagy for pointing that out).

Furthermore Dirichlet proved that if the prime $p \equiv 1 \mod 4$ and $p \equiv 5 \mod 8$ or $p \equiv 9 \mod 16$, the equation $x^2 - 2py^2 = -1$ has still integer solutions (reference: https://www.forgottenbooks.com/en/download/ThePellEquation_10024828.pdf pag. 80)

So you can say that if $p$ is a prime and $p \equiv 5 \mod 8$ or $p \equiv 9 \mod 16$ both NPEₚ NPE₂ₚ have integer solutions

Answer (score 4):

*(Too long for a comment.)*

The sequence of integers such that $x^2-py^2=-1$ is solvable is given by,

$$p = 1, 2, 5, 10, 13, 17, 26, 29, 37, 41, 50, 53, 58, 61, 65, 73, 74, 82, 85, 89, 97, 101,\dots$$

which is [A031396](http://oeis.org/A031396), while that of $x^2-2q y^2 = -1$ is (if I did my code right),

$$q = 1, 5, 13, 25, 29, 37, 41, 53, 61, 65, 85, 101, \dots$$

and is not yet in the OEIS.

> **Point 1:** The sequence $p$ does not contain non-square $q$ as a subset.

With limited data, it seems to be the case. But the first missing value is $q=221$, since $x^2-221y^2=-1$ [is not solvable](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%20x%5E2%20-221y%5E2%3D-1%20in%20integers), while $x^2-2\cdot221y^2=-1$ is.

> **Point 2:** There is an infinite number of intersections between $p$ and $q$.

*Proof:* We use the identities,

$$m^2-(m^2+1)\cdot 1^2 = -1$$

$$(2n+1)^2-2\cdot(2n^2+2n+1)\cdot 1^2 = -1$$

Equate,

$$m^2+1 = 2n^2+2n+1$$

and turns out to be a well-known Pell equation in disguise,

$$(2n+1)^2-2m^2 = 1$$

$$u^2-2v^2=1$$

with solutions $(u,v) = (3,2),\,(17,12),\,(99,70),\dots$ and proves there is an *infinite* number of $d$ such that

$$x^2-dy^2 = -1$$

$$x^2-2dy^2 = -1$$

is both solvable.

**P.S.** However, to characterize all $d$ seems to be difficult.

Comment: The number 25 is in your list of values of $q$, so that is the first missing value.

Comment: @KConrad: Oops, I was not being precise. I was focusing on whether there were missing _non-square_ $q$.